# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'x' but this dictionary requires a model item of type PagedList.IPagedList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, pagedlist

I have multiple classes to be shown in a view so I used a viewmodel

myViewModel

```
 public class myViewModel
{
    public PagedList.IPagedList<entities1> entities_one { get; set; }
    public PagedList.IPagedList<entities2> entities_two { get; set; }
    public PagedList.IPagedList<entities3> entities_three { get; set; }
}
```

And here's my controller code (other codes omitted)

```
myViewModel model = new myViewModel()
                {
                    entities_one = db.mydatabase.Where(a => a.id == query).OrderBy(a => a.col1).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize),
                    entities_two = db.mydatabase.Where(a => a.id == query).OrderBy(a => a.col1).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize),
                    entities_three = db.mydatabase.Where(a => a.id == query).OrderBy(a => a.col1).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize)
                 }

return View(model);
```

Then here's my main view which renders partial view for each entities in tab panes (other codes omitted)

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Proj.Models.myViewModel>

 <div class="tab-content col-xs-12">

    <div class="tab-pane fade in active">
        @if (ViewBag.Successful == "true")
        {
            @Html.Partial("_pv1", Model)
        }
        else
        {
            <h4 style="padding:5px;">No records found.</h4>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade in">
        @if (ViewBag.Successful == "true")
        {
            @Html.Partial("_pv2", Model)
        }
        else
        {
            <h4 style="padding:5px;">No records found.</h4>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade">
        @if (ViewBag.Successful == "true")
        {
            @Html.Partial("_pv3", Model)
        }
        else
        {
            <h4 style="padding:5px;">No records found.</h4>
        }
    </div>
```

And here's one of my partial views

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Proj.Models.myViewModel>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using PagedList;

<ul class="list-group row">

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li class="list-group-item col-xs-12">
        <h6>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.entities_one.Select(a => a.col3))</h6>
    </li>
}
```

```
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, filter = ViewBag.Filter }))
```

However, this returns the following error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Proj.Models.myViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'PagedList.IPagedList`1[Proj.Models.myViewModel]'.

Comment: The error is self explanatory. Your view expects `IPagedList<myViewModel>` but you passing it `myViewModel`. Change the view to `@modelProj.Models.myViewModel` and then `@Html.Partial("_pv1", Model.entities_one)` etc and the partials will be `@model IPagedList<entities1>` etc

Comment: I tried doing that but it returned, `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type` `'PagedList.IPagedList`1[Proj.Models.entities_one]'`, `but this dictionary requires a model item of type` `'PagedList.IPagedList`1[Proj.Models.myViewModel]'`.`

Comment: Then you did not try it! Read the comment again.

Comment: I didn't see the last part of your comment earlier.